# How to show images uploaded only on "read more?"

Tags: 7

How to show images uploaded only on "read more?"

drupal is so confusing...

Comment: Hello. Could you be more specific? Where are you uploading your images? Fields in content type? Media library of some kind? What are you using to create shortened versions of your articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Read more' button appears on the teaser display.

If you go to **/admin/structure/types** and select your content type, under the 'Manage display' tab you will see the display types for that content. Select 'teaser' and make the images 'Hidden' on the teaser. Then the images will only display when the full node is viewed.